# Is there any way to replicate postgres database in linode

Tags: database, postgresql, psql, database-replication, linode

I have a django project up and running. I am using linode database service for postgresql database. Now I want a replicate database of my original database just for read operations. When I research I only found way to do it if database is in ubuntu instance or something like that. Does linode provide some services to replicate database? If not how can I do that?